# Multiple query Joins in windows form application C# with MS Access not working

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have three tables in MS Access database

> users,
>   rooms,
>   room_history

room_history contains both users,rooms id. when I try to join users with room_history data successfully retrieve same goes with rooms and room_history. 
Here is my query for joining all three tables.

```
"SELECT users.*,rooms.room_id,rooms.room_name,rooms.type,room_history.start_date,room_history.end_date FROM users " +
                "LEFT JOIN room_history ON room_history.user_id= users.user_id " +
                "LEFT JOIN rooms ON room_history.room_id = rooms.room_id";
```

Using above query following error occurs.

> syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'room_history.user_id = users.user_id LEFT JOIN rooms on room_history.room_id = rooms.room_i'

I check/change my database tables name, compact the database.

Comment: You miss some parenthesis around the joins - use the GUI query designer to sort it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to get to fundamentals here - and design this query using the Access query design view tool? ... rather than attempting to resolve this using a text based sql statement...

Once you make the query in Access using the query design feature, and verify that it runs correctly in returning the correct record set - - then use the option to put it into SQL View (rather than Design View) in order to see the text based sql statement.

Comment: Thanks Man, That really help

Answer (score 0):

Try with table alias's instead - the problem appears to be **Type** is a reserved SQL keyword:

```
SELECT U.*,R.room_id,R.room_name,R.[type],RH.start_date,RH.end_date FROM users U
LEFT JOIN room_history RH ON RH.user_id= U.user_id
LEFT JOIN room R ON RH.room_id = R.room_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your naming convention.

You used

```
rooms.type
```

where `type` is a reserved word of your database.

the error you receive

```
syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'room_history.user_id = users.user_id LEFT JOIN rooms on room_history.room_id = rooms.room_i'
```

pertains to naming conventions which below link discusses.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/932994/you-receive-an-error-message-when-you-run-a-query-in-microsoft-access

If you would insist to use your query "as is" you may simply put brackets ([]) on all of your table names that are reserve words, (e.g `[type], [start_date],[user_id]`)

Comment: I check with that. My all fields starting with small letters some of them contains underscore like user_id. That doesn't help anyways.
I cant understand my two tables join successfully when I try to join with third table the problem arise

Comment: @MuhammadUsamaSaeed I have updated my answer, see if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, using access query design now query look like this
SELECT users.*, room_history.start_date, room_history.end_date, rooms.room_name
FROM rooms INNER JOIN (users INNER JOIN room_history ON users.user_id = room_history.occupant_id) ON rooms.room_id = room_history.room_id;
error change to  "no value given for required parameter"

Comment: I think that error pertains to your parameter explicitly, could you try to verify at your end if your parameter does not receive any `NULL` values?